# How do I extract this LinqToSql data into a POCO object?

Tags: c#, .net, linq-to-sql, poco

with my Repository classes, I use `LinqToSql` to retrieve the data from the repository (eg. Sql Server 2008, in my example). I place the result data into a `POCO` object. Works great :)

Now, if my `POCO` object has a child property, (which is another `POCO` object or an IList), i'm trying to figure out a way to populate that data. I'm just not too sure how to do this.

Here's some sample code i have. Please note the last property I'm setting. It compiles, but it's not 'right'. It's not the POCO object instance .. and i'm not sure how to code that last line.

```
public IQueryable<GameFile> GetGameFiles(bool includeUserIdAccess)
{
    return (from q in Database.Files
            select new Core.GameFile
            {
                CheckedOn = q.CheckedOn.Value,
                FileName = q.FileName,
                GameFileId = q.FileId,
                GameType = (Core.GameType)q.GameTypeId,
                IsActive = q.IsActive,
                LastFilePosition = q.LastFilePosition.Value,
                UniqueName = q.UniqueName,
                UpdatedOn = q.UpdatedOn.Value,

                // Now any children....
                // NOTE: I wish to create a POCO object
                //        that has an int UserId _and_ a string Name.
                UserAccess = includeUserIdAccess ?
                    q.FileUserAccesses.Select(x => x.UserId).ToList() : null
            });
}
```

Notes:

- Database.Files => The File table.
- Database.FilesUserAccess => the FilesUserAccess table .. which users have access to the GameFiles / Files table.

#### Update

I've now got a suggestion to extract the children results into their respective `POCO` classes, but this is what the `Visual Studio Debugger` is saying the class is :-

[image]

Why is it a `System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.Implementation.ObjectMaterializer<..>`

`.Convert<Core.GameFile>` and not a `List<Core.GameFile>` containing the `POCO's`?

Any suggestions what that is / what I've done wrong?

#### Update 2:

this is what i've done to extract the children data into their respective poco's..

```
// Now any children....
UserIdAccess = includeUserIdAccess ? 
    (from x in q.FileUserAccesses
     select x.UserId).ToList() : null,
LogEntries = includeUserIdAccess ? 
    (from x in q.LogEntries
     select new Core.LogEntry
     {
         ClientGuid = x.ClientGuid,
         ClientIpAndPort = x.ClientIpAndPort,
         // ... snip other properties
         Violation = x.Violation
     }).ToList() : null
```

Comment: I think you may be returning a query rather than a result (hard to say as we can't see the revised code...?)

Comment: Yep, it's returning a query (the method) but that should be a problem, right? or is that EXACTLY the problem? i shouldn't be creating a .ToList() cause this will cause it to 'execute' ?

Comment: I think its probably is the issue - you're returning IQueryable rather than anything concrete by way of POCO objects. Step back and run the queries to get concrete results i.e. you want a test app that has the least amount of code required to allow you to play and see what evaluating the queries gives you.

Answer (score 1):

I think that all you need to do is to put another Linq query in here:

```
q.FileUserAccesses.Select(x => x.UserId).ToList()
```

i.e. You want to select data from the FileUserAccess records - which I'm assuming are Linq to SQL classes, so to do this you can have something like:

```
(from fua in q.FileUserAccesses
select new PocoType
{
   UserID = fua.UserID, 
   Name = fua.User.UserName // Not sure at this point where the name comes from
}).ToList()
```

That should get you pointed in the right direction at least.

Comment: I can't see how your suggestion could work .. because where is the connection to the main PARENT instance? Your code will return ALL rows from the FileUserAccesses table. I need only the rows that exist for the parent table (table Files) .. for each row which the parent L2S query will return.

Comment: From the code you've given, I would expect a FK relations ship between files and user accesses in the database reflected in your Linq to SQL model - therefore in the Linq query q.FileUserAccesses is an enumerable collection of FileUserAccess records representing the "child" user access records for the File q. It *won't* (shouldn't!) return all the rows because we're selecting just those records defined by the relationship between File and FileUserAccess for a specific file.

Comment: Awesome :) i totally missed the 'q.FileUserAccesses' bit and just thought it was a _new_ query, not extending the existing one!

Comment: Hmm. interesting. Updated the inital post now Murph.

Comment: Can I just check - have we addressed the initial question?

Comment: Nope -> it's not returning poco's for the children.. but this weird ObjectMaterializer<..> result.

Answer (score 0):

What is the type of UserIdAccess?  How is it not 'right'?  Are you getting the 'wrong' data?  if so have you checked your database directly to make sure the 'right' data is there?

Comment: It's not right because i'm not creating any poco classes. This is a simple example, that is .. i'm just getting an list of ints. What if i wanted to get a list of (poco) foo's?